# Saying "Elokim" when not referring to Hashem

Tags: minhag, words, hebrew, shemos-sacred-names, language

People often say "Elokim" instead of "Elohim" when speaking in order to avoid taking God's name in vain. I have observed, however, that some people always substitute the word "elokim" for "elohim" even if they are not specifically talking about Hashem. For example, I have heard the posuk quoted,

> לא יהיה לך **אלוקים** אחרים על פני
>
> You shall have no other **gods** before me

I also have often heard the word "keil" substituted for "eil" when the word does not refer to God. Is this an error on the part of the person speaking, or is there some real reason why one should substitute these words?

In [Likutei Sichos 22 page 453](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14947&st=&pgnum=467&hilite=), the Lubavitcher Rebbe writes

> **מורגל בפי העולם לומר אלקים אחרים (בקו"ף, אף שמדובר בעבודה-זרה)**. ואולי יש לקשר עם פירוש הרמב"ן דברים (כא, כב) כנען כו' שחשש כו

I take this to mean that this is a widespread custom, and he makes a possible connection to something from the Ramban.

Clarification: The Ramban that is quoted comes from [Ramban's commentary to Deuteronomy chapter 21, verse 22](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=258).

Comment: it seems to be an error since i think a sofer can erase it.

Comment: You have "seen" this, or heard it?

Comment: And I think it's an error.

Comment: @SethJ heard it

Comment: Did you hear it from anyone of stature?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure. I have definitely heard it from many people, but I don't remember who.

Comment: @Daniel Finding/including such a detail would help a potential answerer know how strong a 'defense' of such practice he ought to aim to mount.

Comment: I once read or heard somewhere that the Lubavitcher Rebbe would always say Elokim Acherim, based on the Tanya that explains that everything gets its life-giving force from G-d, even Impurity, and the definition of Elokim Acherim is that that they receive their life from the Achorayim aspects of G-d's life-giving force. -- See that Tanya here http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tDate=9/20/2013 -- I don't remember where I saw it though, it might have been somewhere on this site.

Comment: @DoubleAA The Lubavitcher Rebbe definitely at least noted that people do this and seems to support doing it. See the edit to the question.

Comment: I once heard somebody (not a rabbi) explain this as like telecon's "common carrier" argument: if he always said it this way he was not responsible for figuring out when it did or didn't refer to Hashem, and since he wasn't completely fluent he didn't want the obligation.  So, essentially, it's easier, or better safe than sorry.

Comment: @Daniel Why did you edit an answer into the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think it's an answer. Just because the Rebbe sees that it is a widespread custom does not mean that it is the correct custom. I also don't know which Ramban he is connecting the practice to.

Comment: @Daniel it seems that the Ramban compares hanging a human to kavyachol .... The same could be said about using a name of Hashem lightly (even though in context it refers to **not** Hashem).

Comment: The context seems to imply that it's a proper minhag. In other words, you have your answer in the question.

Comment: Everyone who I've spoken to ever, in any community, seem to say it as it's spelled when it's in reference to idols or judges and substitute a kuf for the hei when speaking about Hashem. Not posting this as an answer because I don't actually have a source. Maybe I'll take a look in Ta'amei HaMinhagim later.

Comment: Thanks to the Bar Ilan Responsa Project (online version), I can say that although most published commentaries and Poskim used Elohim Acheirim when referring to Avodah Zarah, there are at least 3 notable Rabbanim that used Elokim Acheirim: The Sanz-Klausenberger Rebbe (Divrei Yatziv OC 76:6), the "Beis Yotzchok", YD 2:103:2, and Rabbi Ben Tzion Uziel (Mishpetei Uziel 2:YD:16).