# (Sort of) Writing the Name of God

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, aramaic

I'm taking an Aramaic class, and one of the words that came up in the text I'm reading is "yehuweh," meaning "he will become" (in context, "he will become my successor).  It is spelled with the exact four letters as the name of God.

Since it's not actually the name of God - only spelled the exact same way - do I treat it as such?  Should I not dispose of my notes?

Comment: I see no reason that would have any Kedusha. We have many instances of the letters of names of God being written with other meanings with no problem at all.

Comment: I made a similar argument here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/how-could-the-numerals-and-be-used-irreverently/10692#comment81212_10692

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps extra stringency is appropriate with the *Shem Havaya*, sort of in the same vein as *T'rumas HaDeshen* (*P'sakim* §171): אולי י"ל דהואיל והוא מן השם המיוחד בכתיבתו יש להחמיר יותר.

Comment: @Fred That's talking about a place where there is kavana, but no tzura. You can even imagine prohibiting this to someone who actually speaks Aramaic??

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think this question could be effectively and productively answered via citation of a source that indicates that kavana is essential to an expression of a name being considered holy. If it calls out (as it were) the tetragrammaton by name (as it were), so much the better.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's why I wrote "perhaps" and "sort of in the same vein." But the *p'sak* does seem to give significance to the *tzura*, as well. And yes, I can imagine prohibiting it to anyone, even if it was meant as a different word in a different language but with the same alphabet (which is not to say I think it is prohibited, only that I can entertain the possibility). That's the point of my above comment, and that's why I think this is a good question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses The "Keset ha-Sofer" does say something like this, but only in the context of sofrut. Halakha 10:6 here: http://www.hasoferet.com/ritual/keset/chapter10.shtml

Comment: Origin discussion at Reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/1rji3d/sortof_writing_the_name_of_god/

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29074 as well as http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28084 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16113

Comment: Rambam (*Hil. Y'sodei HaTorah* 6:9) rules in accordance with the *Tanna Kamma* (*Sh'vuos* 35b; *Sof'rim* 4:7) and the *Y'rushalmi* (*M'gilla* 1:9) that usage of that name in *Shof'tim* (17,18) is considered profane. Even R' Eliezer who disagrees in the case of Micha (במיכה יש מהן חול ויש מהן קדש אלף למד חול יוד הי קדש) maintains that the letters of *shem Havaya* are profane in the case of *pilegesh b'giv'a* (see also Meiri on N'darim 25a and Sh'vu'os 29a). This seems to indicate that it is possible to have a profane form of the *shem Havaya* just as it is possible with other names of HaShem.

Comment: @DoubleAA The *Y'rei'im* ([§366](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15223&st=&pgnum=187)), the *Hagahos Maimoniyos* (*Hil. Y'sodei HaTorah* 6:1), and the Tashbetz (I, §177) all rule there's no problem if the person's intent wasn't to write HaShem's Name. The *Shach* (YD 276:12, as understood by *Bei'ur Halacha* on 32:3) writes more stringently that it's forbidden to erase a Holy Name written without specific intent, but it can be erased if it's clearly written as a *shem chol*. *Igros Moshe* (YD 1:172) seems to take a middle view, following the *Shach* for only the *Shem Havaya*.

Comment: @DoubleAA There appear to be multiple opinions on this issue. For some discussion, see [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=107893&rid=60), [here](http://shaalvim.co.il/torah/view.asp?id=139) (para. beginning "האם יש קדושה"), [here](http://www.bsd-paz.org/Texts/AteretPaz_v2_Yore_Dayah/html/E7ECF75FE05FEBF8EA5FE15FE9E5F8E45FE3F2E45FF1E9EEEF5FE9E25FE0E5FA5FE7.htm), [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=869&st=&pgnum=122), and [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=994&pgnum=55).

Comment: @Fred In the Bavli it is indeed R' Eliezer who holds kodesh by micha but chol by givah, but in Sofrim it's R' Yosi who holds kodesh by micha and R' Eliezer who holds chol by givah, so there's no proof *everyone* holds of the existence of a chol name since R' Yosi may agree with R' Yehoshua about givah. (I haven't checked any manuscripts to see if the names in the printed versions are at all accurate.)

Answer (score 3):

One may both write, erase, and speak the word יְהֻוֶה.

Source: Rabbi Leib Tropper, *talmid muvhak* of Rabbi Pinchas Sheinberg.

---

<sup>Please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/34637/edit) to include a *dagesh* in the *vav* (יְהֻוֶּה) if you know it should be there.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The Shach in Yoreh Deah 206 #12 references a responsa of his where he rules that a mundane word which resembles a holy name such as והייתם כאלהים may be erased. This was said concerning a Seffer Torah.

Those are his words. There would be no reason to be more stringent with a word which resembles a holy name written anywhere else.

[The Shach mentions two more categories which I'll quote. Whereas a holy name written without kedusha can only be erased in order to fix what is being written. And a holy name with kedusha can never be erased. Even if it was written with intention to be cut out and put in geniza, it is not allowed to do this. ]